# edit Textfield with a little delay

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield

I working with swift 4 for macOS and have a NSTableView with custom Cells.
In my row are two textfields (style: borderless and no background color)

Normally, you click on a textfield and it will directly be editable.
In my case, you click on the textfield and after a short delay it will be editable.

But I don't understand why is there such a delay.
Have anybody an idea?

**Better Example**

*My tableview with Custom Cell View (delay problem)*
[image]

*Another tableview without Custom Cell View (no delay problem)*
[image]

I hope you can see the difference. I do both situations with the same steps.

1. Select Row (click)
2. Select textfield (click)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you’re selecting the table view cell first. Try `tableView.allowsSelection = false`

Comment: my first click on `Max Power` select the row and bring the textfield automatically in "edit-mode". the second click on `45 years old` bring this textfield in "edit-mode" (the row is selected in this moment). but in both cases, there is a delay. and my rows have to be selectable